# Ограничение ввода числа в input с помощью NumberFormat isAllowed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

есть код, который в принципе работает так что если в поле вписать число больше чем maxValue, то оно просто не пишется, но для пользователя это неудобно. Как сделать так, чтобы число автоматически заменялось на максимальное?
вот код:

```
isAllowed={values => {
    const { formattedValue, floatValue } = values;
    if (attributes.maxValue)
      return formattedValue === '' || floatValue <= attributes.maxValue;
    return values;
       }}
```

Comment: `if number > maxAllowed then number = maxAllowed` - псевдокод

Comment: Попробовал поменять - не особо вышло:

    `
    isAllowed={values => {
            const { formattedValue, floatValue } = values;
            if (attributes.maxValue)
              if (values > attributes.maxValue)
                return (
                  floatValue <= attributes.maxValue || formattedValue === attributes.maxValue
                );
            return values;
          }}
`

Comment: Я хотел бы попробовать использовать хук useState для замены числа весто неподходящего, но в рамках это задачи state заюзать не получается